# Centering button components in nextjs app?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, next.js

I am using a button within one of my nextjs pages that exists on its own row. I would like the button to appear in the middle of the page because I believe it would look best on both PC and mobile, but no matter what I try nothing seems to get the button element to move from its original position on the far left of the page.

Manually setting margin-left and margin-right to specific percentages that push the button as close to the center of the page without cramming the buttons text into the next line is the singular thing I've found that manages to get the button to move but it doesn't look great and isn't practical. Depending on the state of the page the text within the button can be varying lengths so hard-coded left and right margins don't actually center the button.

I have tried 'margin: auto;', text-align/align-items/justify-content: center;, and even wrapping the button in a div to try and center it with css on the div instead of the button.

Here's what I currently have:

```
return (
    <div className={cx('pd-container')}>
      <h1 className={cx('pd-title')}>{product.title}</h1>
      <img className={cx('pd-img')} src={`/productPhotos/${product.id}.jpeg`} alt={product.title} />
      <p className={cx('pd-price')}>Price: ${product.price}</p>
      {isCheckout ? (
        <CheckoutButton onCheckout={handleCheckout}/>
      ) : (
        <CartButton onAddToCart={handleAddToCart} />
      )}
    </div>
  );
```

```
.pd-container {
    align-items: center;
}
```

```
import React from 'react';
import classNames from 'classnames/bind';
import styles from './CartButton.module.css'; 

const cx = classNames.bind(styles);

const CartButton = ({ onAddToCart }) => {
    return <button onClick={onAddToCart} className={cx('cart-button')}>Add To Cart</button>;
};
  
export default CartButton;
```

```
.cart-button {
    background-color: #007bff; /* Blue color for the button background */
    color: white;
    padding: 12px 24px;
    font-size: 16px;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 4px;
    cursor: pointer;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2); /* Add a subtle box shadow */
    transition: background-color 0.3s ease; /* Smooth transition on hover */
    text-align: center;
  }
  
  .cart-button:hover {
    background-color: #0056b3; /* Darker blue on hover */
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think, you are forgotten about display:flex property in CSS.
You have to add display:flex; flex-direction:column; justify-content:center;
align-items:center; in the pd-container class.
You can see about display:flex in https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp.
align-items and justify-content properties are not working without display:flex;.
justify-content handles the main-axios of display-direction and align-items handles the cross-axios of display-direction.
So, if the display-direction is row, then justify-content handles the horizontal and align-items handles the vertical axios.
Hope this could be helpful for you.
Thank you.